# What is the way to use stringtokenizer

Tags: java, string

I have used the code to extract each digit of the string,my motive is to store it in an integer array,but i am unable to extract all the digits of the string

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
   class jdsh
    {
        public static void main()
        {int i,j;
            String a="1 2 3 4";
            StringTokenizer aa= new StringTokenizer(a);
            for(i=0;i<=aa.countTokens();i++)
            System.out.println(aa.nextToken());
        }
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't use it at all. From the JavaDoc: _StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead._

Comment: Use `\\d+` to match digits.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that

```
String[] subs = a.split(" ");

for(String sub : subs){
    System.out.println(sub);
}
```

It will only work if you digits are only separated by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Just use split method, it will return an array of space split chars.

```
String[] spliArr = a.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `hasMoreElemenents()` for iterate token list.

```
String string = "1 2 3 4";
StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(string);
while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
    System.out.println(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
}
```